# Facebook Connect with site specific signup

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-login

I was wondering is there a way of allowing users to log in to your site with facebook connect but then prompt them to give email permissions (not to their @facbook.com email address) or create a profile on your site?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, while using facebook login on your website, you need to register as an app on developer.facebook.com, so after registering your app, you can specify the permissions you want in the apps setting, see this screenshot.

http://www.pastemehere.com/ztbfj51h

to get email, you need to specify "email" as permission.
To create a profile, import all data like name, gender etc and make a profile out of it once the user permits.

now add this code on your site to check whether the user gave you all required permssions or not, If not, you redirect them back to permissions' page using FB.login with required permissions as scope.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log("got all permissions");
    callReqFunc();
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    console.log("dint get full permissions");
    FB.login(function(response) {
    }, {scope: 'publish_stream, friends_photos'});
    callReqFunc();
   } else {
    console.log("user not logged in fb"); 
  } });
```

Comment: Thanks!, It is an interesting solution but i guess you are still hoping they will allow you to use their email after they have managed to sign in. Is there a way to get them to sign up for a profile on my site (with permissions etc) then link to their facebook account afterwards? mainly so they can comment on posts which link to their facebook account?

Comment: my solution is the first step of the thing you want, you add permissions there in app settings, so when they visit your website for first time, they are asked for permissions, now after they login in, you query to see whether they gave you all permssions or not, If not, you use FB.login() in js sdk to redirect them to permissions page.